# how to use GROUP_CONCAT of two columns with query

Tags: mysql, group-concat

My query like this

```
SELECT * FROM  semesters WHERE student_id = 434 AND marks_id <=  576 AND semester_id <=  2345
```

Iam having one table "semesters" iam getting  output with the following data in MySQL with my query:

```
id       semester_id       exam_id      student_id   marks_id
1          2344               25            434       255
2          2344               34            434       575 
3          2345               48            434       576
```

how do I get it into the following format with my query?

```
 id          semester_id        exam_id      student_id   marks_id
 1             2344              25,34          434       255,575
 2             2345               48            434         576
```

I want semster_id 2344 having two exam_ids, iwant to merge two exam_ids and marks_id  in single row with comma seperated.think I have to use GROUP_CONCAT, but I'm not sure how it works.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use MySQL `GROUP_CONCAT` with `group by`

```
SELECT *,GROUP_CONCAT(exam_id) as exam_id,GROUP_CONCAT(marks_id) 
as marks_id FROM  semesters group by semester_id
```

Comment: This works because the default separator is `,`. For other separators one may use `GROUP_CONCAT(exam_id, SEPARATOR 'some_character')`.

Comment: @Rahautos    its shows  [BLOB - 6 B]  like that ,how to convert it

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(exam_id, CHAR(8)))

Comment: SELECT *,GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(exam_id, CHAR(8))) as exam_id,GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(marks_id, CHAR(8))) 
as marks_id FROM  semesters group by semester_id

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT((exam_id) separator ',')
     , GROUP_CONCAT((marks_id) separator ',')
FROM semesters
WHERE student_id = 434
    AND marks_id <=  576
    AND semester_id <=  2345
GROUP BY semester_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use GROUP_CONCAT, but I would suggest forcing the order and coping with NULL values in the columns. So that the exams and marks should match up even if one is null:-

```
SELECT semester_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(exam_id, '') ORDER BY id),
    student_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(marks_id, '') ORDER BY id)
FROM  semesters 
WHERE student_id = 434 
AND marks_id <=  576 
AND semester_id <=  2345
GROUP BY semester_id, 
        student_id
```

If you need a sequential id you probably need to manually create it with a variable:-

```
SELECT  @cnt:=@cnt + 1 AS id,
        sub0.semester_id,
        sub0.exam_id_out,
        sub0.student_id,
        sub0.marks_id_out
FROM
(
    SELECT semester_id,
        GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(exam_id, '') ORDER BY id) AS exam_id_out,
        student_id,
        GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(marks_id, '') ORDER BY id) AS marks_id_out
    FROM  semesters 
    WHERE student_id = 434 
    AND marks_id <=  576 
    AND semester_id <=  2345
    GROUP BY semester_id, 
            student_id
    ORDER BY semester_id
) sub0
CROSS JOIN 
(
    SELECT @cnt:=0
) sub1
```